# How to extract value at "final visit" from a data set with repeated measurement in R?

Tags: r, data-extraction

Suppose I have a data frame with repeated measurements:

```
 >m
 id  age    diagnosis
  1   4         0
  1   7         1
  1   9         0
  2   6         1
  4   9         1
  4   10        0
```

Diagnosis is not time-invariant. How can I extract the diagnosis result at final visit (oldest age) to get something like this?

```
id  age    diagnosis
 1   9         0
 2   6         1
 4   10        0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try *data.table*'s `last()`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, last(.SD), by = id]
#    id age diagnosis
# 1:  1   9         0
# 2:  2   6         1
# 3:  4  10         0
```

Or with *dplyr* `slice(., n())`

```
library(dplyr)
slice(group_by(df, id), n())
# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: id [3]
#
#      id   age diagnosis
#   (int) (int)     (int)
# 1     1     9         0
# 2     2     6         1
# 3     4    10         0
```

Comment: Base equivalent: `m[by(seq_len(nrow(m)), m$id, FUN=tail, 1),]`

Comment: Or even better/quicker - `m[tapply(seq_len(nrow(m)), m$id, FUN=tail, 1),]`

Answer (score 0):

Or using `duplicated` from `base R`, we get the logical index to subset the rows.

```
m[!duplicated(m$id,fromLast=TRUE),]
#   id age diagnosis
#3  1   9         0
#4  2   6         1
#6  4  10         0
```